# Coding within labels and datasets table from chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Hi I would like to use a while loop within the labels to display the hours and I would like to use a while loop within the datasets to display my array.

My problem is i cant code within the labels and the dataset. i tried

```
label: [{CODE}]
datasets: [{CODE}]
```

But it doesn't work & the documentation on charts.js didnt help me.

```
        var myChartObject = document.getElementById('myChartHistory');
        var chart = new Chart(myChartObject,{
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: [//WANT TO CODE HERE],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "GATEWAY1",
                    fill: true,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    data: [//WANT TO CODE HERE], 
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do. But anyway  you can do  something like this: `labels:  someMethod()` and  `someMethod` should return  array of labels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are looking to format `labels` before passing them to the `chart.js`

You can do it like below:

```
//Below are the original Labels
var labels = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'];


//Run a while loop and format them as you want.
index = 0;
while (index < labels.length) { 
    labels[index] += index; 
    index++; 
}


       var myChartObject = document.getElementById('myChartHistory');
        var chart = new Chart(myChartObject,{
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: labels,  //pass the formatted labels
                datasets: [{
                    label: "GATEWAY1",
                    fill: true,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    data: [//WANT TO CODE HERE],
```

You can check the Demo at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/615n94vc/)

Comment: @noSkill06s happy to help. Could you please upvote and accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: i made the upvote i twill display in 15 mins how can i accept the answer? ok i got it